# Batch set init be case sensitive

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script which will convert letters to numbers.
But I cannot get it to be case sensitive - any suggestion?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set init="A=1" "a=2" "B=3" "b=4" "C=5" "c=6"
set %init: =&set %
set "nickname= "
set /P "nickname=Enter here: "
set "nickname=%nickname: =%"
if not defined nickname goto :EOF
set "out="
set "nums="
set "sum=0"
:loop
   set "char=%nickname:~0,1%"
   set "out=%out%%char%"
   set /A "code=%char%, sum+=code"
   set "nums=%nums%%code%"
set "nickname=%nickname:~1%"
IF DEFINED nickname GOTO :loop
ECHO original: %out%
ECHO converted to: %nums%
pause
```

So if I enter Aa it converts to 22 - but should be 12.
Thanks! :)

I have searched and tried different solutions to similar problems found on stackoverflow.
But no luck so far.
If I enter Aa it converts to 22 - but should be 12.

Comment: In a Command Prompt window, if you type ```echo %WINDIR%^|%windir%^|%wInDiR%```, and press the `[ENTER]` key, what do you see? and does that show you your inherent issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) who [posted the following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865106/batch-set-init-be-case-sensitive/75866434#comment133819642_75865106) which worked perfectly!

> Replace the six lines below `:loop` by `for %%G in ("A=1" "a=2" "B=3" "b=4" "C=5" "c=6") do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%I in (%%G) do if "%nickname:~0,1%" == "%%I" set "nums=%nums%%%J" & set "nickname=%nickname:~1%" & if defined nickname (goto loop) else goto OutputResult` and replace `ECHO original: %out%` by `:OutputResult`.

Comment: Please do not add comments directed to individuals to your answer. Please also, format the code you have posted. There is an `Edit` link for you to use, in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

There could be used the following code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:UserPrompt
set "Nickname="
set /P "Nickname=Enter nickname: " || goto UserPrompt
rem Remove all double quotes from the entered string.
set "Nickname=%Nickname:"=%"
if not defined Nickname goto UserPrompt
rem Remove all spaces from the entered string.
set "Nickname=%Nickname: =%"
if not defined Nickname goto UserPrompt
set "Original=%Nickname%"
set "Numbers="

:Loop
for %%G in ("A=1" "a=2" "B=3" "b=4" "C=5" "c=6") do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%I in (%%G) do if "%Nickname:~0,1%" == "%%I" set "Numbers=%Numbers%%%J" & set "Nickname=%Nickname:~1%" & if defined Nickname (goto Loop) else goto OutputResult
set "Nickname=%Nickname:~1%"
if defined Nickname goto Loop

:OutputResult
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Original: !Original!
echo Converted to: !Numbers!
endlocal
endlocal
pause
```

There is output for the user input `"Asterix & Obelix"`:

```
Original: Asterix&Obelix
Converted to: 14
```

The code is fail-safe and secure which means independent on what the user inputs on prompt, the Windows *Command Processor* runs really the commands as written in the batch file and does never exit because of a syntax error caused by the string input by the user.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)